# How to connect multiple real devices to a single shadow in AWS IoT

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

I've multiple thermometers(100+). I want them to connect to a single shadow using the same set of certificates, and publish data to the same topic. The data contains a unique identifier to distinguish between thermometers.

Found a similar [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43924728/5265359) and the answers there suggest that it is, although discouraged, possible. But they're far from clarity.

I'm new to AWS and IoT and have been struggling for 3 days straight. Are there any steps that can be followed so that I can receive data from multiple thermometers via a single topic using a single set of certificates?

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible as detailed in your link, and it took us 5 minutes to
reproduce as in this Youtube video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPGPH8vMpSw

with the MQTT lab at https://mqttlab.iotsim.io/aws/ . 2 different devices with
the same TLS configuration, one with color yellow, the other with color cyan.
QED